# How to stop Matlab quantising a graph?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

So I have 2 sine waves, one is the input to a system, the other being the output of the anti-aliasing bessel filter on the output of the system. There is a slight phase difference, so I've been using Matlab to work out the difference between the two waves. I then plot them both to compare them - however I get this:
[image: Figure 1]

As you can see, the input wave is a sine wave, however the output wave appears to be being quantised. In comparison, here's the two waves before I take the phase difference out:
[image: Figure 2]

As you can see the Bessel output is also a smooth sine wave.
Here's the code I'm using to plot the first graph:

```
yyaxis left
plot(Time(1:length(s1a1)),CIN(1:length(s1a1)))
ylabel('CIN')
yyaxis right
plot(Time(1:length(s1a1)),Bessel(-lagDiff+1:end))
ylabel('Bessel Out')
xlabel('Time')
title('CIN vs Bessel')
```

And here's the code for the second:

```
yyaxis left
plot(Time,CIN)
ylabel('CIN')
yyaxis right
plot(Time,Bessel)
ylabel('Bessel Out')
xlabel('Time')
title('CIN vs Bessel')
```

I'm using the exact same variables, the only difference is instead of using the whole length of the data I'm using only a portion. The weird thing is that this works fine for CIN - it's perfectly normal, only when I do it for Bessel does it do this weird quantisation thing.

Would appreciate if I could get a solution - I've already tried interp1 function with spline as the method, and that doesn't change anything. As well as that, I need to use this data elsewhere outside of MATLAB so I can't really alter it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some edits for MCV Example.

I have reproduced my input wave and output wave roughly using these functions:

```
Time = 0:0.00002:4;
Bessel = 0.1+(sin(((2*pi*1).*Time)-1)).*0.05;
CIN = 4400+(sin((2*pi*1).*Time).*4000);
L = length(Bessel);
L = L/20;
L=round(L);
Value = Bessel(L);
Bessel(1:L) = linspace(0,Value,L);
```

Code being used to remove phase shift is:

```
Fs = 50000;
t1 = (0:length(Bessel)-1)/Fs;
t2 = (0:length(CIN)-1)/Fs;
[acor,lag] = xcorr(CIN,Bessel);
[~,I] = max(abs(acor));
lagDiff = lag(I);
timeDiff = lagDiff/Fs;
s1a1 = Bessel(-lagDiff+1:end);
t1a1 = (0:length(s1a1)-1)/Fs;
s2a2 = CIN(1:length(s1a1));
```

When I then run it through my code I get the following:

[image]
It works for these waves, using the exact same code. But the only change I have made is the input wave, which as established above in my 2nd figure, the input wave is not an issue, it's only when I shift it, as in my 1st figure.
I don't know what the issue is, but it's definitely not the input wave.

Comment: How do you calculate the output of Bessel filter?

Comment: I would also assume that there is a problem with your Bessel filter. The quantization looks irregular and it would explain why `interp1` does not solve it. Maybe plot the result of `diff(Bessel)` and look if this looks like a smooth function. If there are many jumps and values often close to zero, it is very likely that your Bessel filter is the problem and not the quantization.

Comment: Bessel is from a simulation run in Cadence of an actual circuit. As I said in the post when I just plot the Bessel value on its own it's a smooth sine wave as it should be, it's when I plot it so it's in phase with the input that this occurs

Comment: It is not the same `Bessel` data you are plotting here. You need to make a [mcve] for this. We can’t tell you what is wrong if you don’t. Making that MCVE will likely show you what the issue is, without having to ask.

Comment: Ok have put through 2 similar waves I've generated in Matlab and they work like it's meant to - only thing I've changed is the input wave, but it doesn't replicate the problem. As above the input wave itself is fine (from second graph) - something is happening when I plot the phase shifted wave. Have posted that code as well, but I haven't changed it and it works for the waves I have generated.

Comment: So that means that, indeed, it is the input data. You maybe modify it somewhere in between plotting the two graphs. If you apply your MCVE code to your original data, what do you see?

Comment: When I put it through MCVE code I still get the quantised output